# How do I scope out why I have two "posts" menus in an admin?

Tags: posts, menus, admin

A site I'm working on has an odd problem: two sets of "posts" menus in the admin. The client brought me on board and says "it's been there a while". How would I go about finding out why there are two sets? The site was brought into WordPress from Drupal. I created the theme, but the client was active in bringing content over. How we got a duplicate "posts" menu I do not know, and neither does he.

Where would I start with figuring this out? I've been trying deactivating and reactivating plug-ins and have had no clues in that regard.

Comment: Do you have duplicate menus in admin? Can you share screenshot here?

Comment: @Vantiya Yes. Here it is: http://prnt.sc/pi63os

Comment: Can you check if the posts and the URL are same for both the Posts Menu?

Comment: @Vantiya Yes, the URLs for all the items in the Posts Menus are the same, and the admin display is the same for both sets. If I could determine why a duplicate set was showing up in the sidebar, I'd be glad to eliminate whatever is causing the extra set.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sir hope these can help:

1. You need to check your database and see if the posts are really duplicated(maybe it is only visual duplicates for same posts), you will need to use a mysql client like phpmyadmin or similar solutions. you will check the `wp_posts` table.
2. Post (content) data are not really in duplicates :
   (only one same post in the database) there's a problem in the wordpress Admin templates files. these are in the `wp-admin` folder.
3. If it is duplicated that means that it was either :

   - human error: posts were inserted in bulk two times and it was the operator error.
   - bug during migration: posts (data-content) were insered two time by a script.
   - hack this is not normal better check your security.

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment so I wrote this as an Answer.